# Is $\mathbb{E}[|X|] \geq |\mathbb{E}[X]|$?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value

Given a random variable $X$, from the definition of the variance, $\mathbb{E}[X^2] \geq \mathbb{E}[X]^2$. It seems intuitive that $\mathbb{E}[|X|] \geq |\mathbb{E}[X]|$ should be true. Is this the case?

Comment: That is almost true : It might be "Equal" too. Change $\gt$ to $\ge$.

Comment: Try and look up Jensen's Inequality. If your intuition tells you that expectation behaves just like the "integration" operator then that is because it is an integration operator

Comment: Apply expectation to $-|X| \leq X \leq |X|$.

Comment: [Expectation inequality involving absolute values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3811554/expectation-inequality-involving-absolute-values) is a duplicate question.

Comment: I made the change >  to ≥.

Answer (score 1):

They could be equal, but other than that you're basically right.  The intuition is that $E[X]$ is a sum with both positive and negative terms, some of which cancel each other out, but $E[|X|]$ has the same terms but all made positive.  (This assumes a discrete random variable; if your random variables are continuous, replace sums with integrals.)

**More generally**: These are both examples of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), which says that $E(f(X)) \ge f(E(X))$ for a random variable X and a convex function $f$.  When we have $f(x) = x^2$ this becomes $E(X^2) \ge E(X)^2$ (the variance is positive); when we have $f(x) = |x|$ this becomes $E(|X|) \ge |E(X)|$, as you observed.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is the pdf of $X$ you have

$$\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\int_Df(x)|x|\mathrm{d}x$$
and
$$|\mathbb{E}[X]|=\left|\int_D f(x)x\mathrm{d}x\right|$$
Appying the absolute value properties:
$$|\mathbb{E}[X]|=\left|\int_D f(x)x\mathrm{d}x\right|\leq \int_D |f(x)\cdot x|\mathrm{d}x=\int_D |f(x)|\cdot|x|\mathrm{d}x=\int_D f(x)|x|\mathrm{d}x=\mathbb{E}[|X|]$$
So
$$|\mathbb{E}[X]|\leq\mathbb{E}[|X|]$$

Note that a $f(x)$ is always non negative, so $|f(x)|=f(x)$